# Magento 1.8x - Group prices dont get adjust based on multiple store

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, magmi, group-price

I want to update group prices in my multiple store website using magmi-importer but the prices are not getting adjusted.

## CSV:

"store" | "websites" | "attribute_set" | "type" | "sku" | "group_price:abc" | "group_price:def"

"ca_en,us_en" | "ca,us" | "Default" | "simple" | "123456" | "69.30,69.30" | "79.65,79.65"

As you will notice in my above CSV data, i am updating different prices in 2 different stores but I am not getting any of my prices getting updated in any store.

Can you some one please help me to sort out how to load grouped prices in multie stores website using magmi?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a complete fix, but for me https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/498 helped.

sreichel made a fix:
"Got it working. In

=> `plugins/extra/itemprocessors/groupprice/grouppriceprocessor.php`

L26

=> `$this->_singleStore should be changed to !$this->_singleStore`."